# How to Fix Mediawiki Confirm Account Extension Error qmail-inject: fatal: unable to parse this line:

Tags: mediawiki

I have an instance of mediawiki installed with an extension called **Confirm Account**. This works fine on my MAMP setup at home. On my MediaTemple.net account I get this error when the extension is run:

**Error sending mail:Unknown error in PHP's mail() function.**

The server error log error is:

```
qmail-inject: fatal: unable to parse this line: Return-Path:apache@ 216.70.110.23:7081
```

I have no idea what to do to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message, or could you enable such?

Comment: I'd love to but that's all that's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [$wgPasswordSender](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/%24wgPasswordSender) to some meaningful email address.